# Screen locker doesn't prompt for password

Tags: 16.04, lock-screen

To be honest, I'm a bit lost. I've reecently upgraded from 12.04 (Kubuntu) to 14.04 and finally to 16.04 (Unity) and aside from some minor issues everything seems fine - except the screen locker, which doesn't prompt me for a password no matter what I try.

I've tried removing gnome-screensaver and installing xscreensaver - no success. I reverted that change - still nothing. I've tried Ctrl+Alt+L, I've tried

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

on the command line - nothing. The screen goes black - as it should - and comes back normally as soon as I press any key or move the mouse.

I must admit that I'm a bit annoyed as this is a serious security issue for me and I never experienced problems for the last twenty years or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install "`Unity Tweak Tool`" with `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`.
 
 Run it from the Launcher and select `System > Security > Enhance system security` by enabling Desktop lock. 
If you password not already existing, set a user-password, replace 'your-user-name' with your real user-name:

```
sudo passwd your-user-name
```

Comment: Actually I was hoping that switching from KDE to Unity would make things a bit simpler... ;-) But thank you for the good (and fast!) answer. Works perfectly for me.